# wireless network disconnects repeatedly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, acer-aspire

I have bought acer VN7 for a few days. The wireless network connects for a 15 minutes and then disconnects for a few minutes and so on. I have tried alot such uninstalling and reinstalling the driver, which is already uptodate, and flushing the DNS, turning off the power options on the wireless adaptor, without any hope.

I have another old HP Compaq laptop, and it works properly, so I am sure the propblem is located in the new hardware or the new System (windows 8.1).
*the picture is after understanding the problem*.[image]

Comment: I have a few questions: what kind of wireless router/AP are You using? Are You trying to connect on b/g/n/ac 2.4 Ghz or 5Ghz? Are there other SSID-s in the area? Whate is the model of your VN7?

Comment: thanks for answering. 
the router is from my ISP: O2, I use 802.11b.g.n(300 Mbit/s). yes there are other SSID, I have Acer Aspire Black Edition VN7-791G-779J

Comment: do you have access to the routers settings?

Comment: yes I can freely

Comment: first You should make sure the wi-fi channel is set to automatic. Also You should play with the encryption a bit. If it is set to WPA1/WPA2, try to disable it for a while and check if the problem is still present.

Comment: I think it has been solved :) you are magician. in the encryption menu there is a choice "WPS - Wi-Fi Protected Setup" it was checked, after I had unchecked the choice, it worked. I hope it is the end. thank you very much. but I will keep watching for hours, if it droped, i will ask here once again. thanks once again.

Comment: This did not solve it, we just found out the root of the problem. If You disable WPS, that leaves your wi-fi without a password which may cause problems in the future. You should just modify the encryption type for testing. There should be an option for WPA2/WPA mixed (personal) mode. You should try that, if that does not work, than try the rest of the options as well.

Comment: I have altered the encryption from WPA 2 AES to WPA /WPA2, and activated the WPS. and seems to be working!

Comment: What was the original encryption type? If it wasn't wpa/wpa2 on the first place, than it seems we solved the problem.

Comment: the original encryption was WPA2 (AES), and I have changed it to WPA /WPA2.

Comment: If You are satisfied with the answer, You can close this post by accepting the answer. If You have more questions, feel confident to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem was caused by the encryption standard that was set.
It seems that the laptop driver could not handle the WPA2 (AES) right.

The solution to this problem is the WPA2/WPA mixed mode, which is a more compatible encryption type that supports both AES and TKIP.

Wireless driver updates in the future might solve this problem.

---

The difference between WPA2(AES) and mixed mode is:

In a "WPA2" only network, all clients must support WPA2(AES) to be able to authenticate.

In a "WPA2/WPA mixed mode" network, one can connect with both WPA(TKIP) and WPA2(AES) clients.

Note that TKIP is not as secure as AES, and therefore WPA2/AES should be used exclusively, if possible. The only exception would be if there are some WPA/TKIP wireless clients on the network that do not support WPA2/AES.

WPA2/WPA mixed mode allows for the coexistence of WPA and WPA2 clients on a common SSID. The passphrase for both WPA and WPA2 clients remains the same, the access point just advertises the different encryption cyphers available to be selected for use by the client. Clients choose which cypher to use for the wireless connection.

Notes:
This mixed mode is also known as: "WPA2 TKIP+AES mode", or "PSK2-mixed mode."

---

For more information about the difference between TKIP and AES, You can read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/204697/wi-fi-security-should-you-use-wpa2-aes-wpa2-tkip-or-both/)